# Why is my C# extension method used in a linq-to-entity query loading the database items into memory instead of running on the DB server?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, extension-methods

I created the following simple extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
{
    return source.GroupBy(keySelector)
                 .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                 .AsQueryable();
}
```

My problem seems to be that the code actually loads the database rows into memory and tries to perform the operations in memory instead of doing what Linq-To-Entities is supposed to do and translate the query to SQL.

One can see above that my extension method does nothing that couldn't be translated to SQL, so why isn't it doing that?

The following two lines of code should be equivalent but the first one executes in <200ms while the other one runs for about 20 minutes before throwing an out of memory exception:

```
// Executes in less than 200ms.
var test_1 = dbContext.SomeTable.GroupBy(row => new { row.SomeColumn, row.SomeOtherColumn })
                                .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                                .Tolist();
// The line below takes some 20 minutes to eventually throw an out of memory exception.
// Notice I'm not even calling ToList().
var test_2 = dbContext.SomeTable.DistinctBy(row => new { row.SomeColumn, row.SomeOtherColumn });
```

Note that this extension method is just an example. It's relatively easy to just not use it and instead use the code defined inside the method directly. I'm saying this because I'm not asking how to make a "DistinctBy" method. Instead, what I'm asking is how to code an extension method that only uses other 'translatable' methods to avoid code repetition.

I understand that I can only use the extension methods provided by the EF provider but that is, in essence, what I'm doing. Can't I let it know that my method can be directly translated to SQL, how does the `GroupBy` method manage to do it?

Comment: what does the `AsQueryable()` call serve you here?

Comment: The ```GroupBy``` and ```FirstOrDefault``` return an IEnumerable. For my extension method to return an IQueryable, I need to use that to convert it to IQueryable. I did try several variations of this extension method which returned IEnumerable, etc., but they all exhibit the same behaviour.

Comment: Unless you do an update the data does not get transfer back to the database.  The Q in linq stands for QUERY which is a read.  For query to run in database you would need a stored procedure.

Comment: Perhaps you must compose the keySelector? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748139/using-expressionfunctsource-tkey-with-iqueryable

Comment: @TheSnowman nope, his keySelector is hard-coded this is not the issue

Comment: Which version of EF?

Comment: try swapping your 2 calls, call the extension first, let me know your results, I expect it's about 1st\2nd call, rather than extesnsion\no-extension

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev 6.3.0

Comment: @jalsh same result, first call crashes.

Comment: @user1841330 crashes or fetchs all rows?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev If I swap the two calls, then the first call (the one with my extension method) hangs. I didn't wait to see if it actually crashes. Just for a bit of context, the table I am using contains 799031 records. After filtering with the `GroupBy` I get 34 records fetched.

Comment: I should also note that indeed the memory usage reported by task manager shows a constant increase while I wait for the extension method call to crash. Furthermore, if I  query a table with far fewer records, both methods are comparable in term of execution time.

Comment: @user1841330 For me both option creates same sql. Tested against EF 6.3.0

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev It didn't occur to me to check the actual SQL. Will report back once I do.

Comment: Your two queries are not the same - what is `DistinctBy`? - it is not part of LINQ to EF.

Comment: I’ve had nothing but trouble with group by being on the SQL side of a query. I almost always put it after an .asenumerable.

Comment: This is embarrassing. I reinstalled oracle dev tools for visual studio and now both queries works just fine. I'm not even sure what to do with this question at this point.

Comment: @RobertRichter speaking of trouble I've only really had issues with oracle DBs. This right here is just another example. From seemingly identical assemblies with the same version but with deprecated methods between them, to annoying environment configuration ('cuz you know, it's not as if we might be developing different apps that might all be using different oracle versions) to having to trim the semicolon ';' at the end of all SQL queries because oracle starts complaining that the command is not properly ended after an update even though it worked fine before.

Comment: I'm 90% certain you're problem is exactly backwards of what you think it is.  You don't want to be doing to much on the database side of things or it can choke in a hurry with N+1 problems, not realizing the initial query had sufficient information.  Have you logged the query with something like DataContext.Database.log=L=>debug.print(L)?  I would highly recommend doing your custom distinct on the client side.  Your comment about Oracle being finicky is revealing.  It hints that you are abusing the SQL side of things.

Comment: I am not going to deny (nor confirm) that I may be abusing the SQL side of things but  at least in this case I don't believe I am. I did not get to a point where I could log the SQL query before reinstalling ODT. In fact, I reinstalled ODT because I was, for no apparent reason, no longer able to update the EDMX model. After reinstalling ODT I was able to update the EDMX and incidentally the linq query started working. I only added a couple of tables in the model, no changes to the one I was querying. So now I'm left wondering if reinstalling ODT or updating the model fixed it.